# Subdivision modifier isn't working

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, subdivision-surface

That's something new. Blender 3.3.0 ignores the subdivision modifier in my scene. Has anybody ever had the problem?
I checked different viewport shading options.
Checked GPU Subdivisions in the preferences.
Render sees the subdivision just fine. Viewport doesn't.
I'm kinda out of options 
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Figured out. In the Render Properties uncheck Simplify